# Bottle: Global Variable 'request' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, openshift, bottle

I am creating a web based application with python where the user enters a search query and data is returned. I used bottle to provide the web framework for this. Openshift is then used to post online. It is a simple post form and the search criteria is then used in the next section using this:

```
@route('/')
def search():
    return '''
        <h1 align="center">Twitter Sentiment Analysis</h1>
        <p align="center">Enter what you would like to search in the search box below</p>
            <form action="/result" method="post" align="center">
                Search: <input name="search" type="text" />
                <input value="Search" type="submit" />
            </form>
        '''

@route('/result', method='POST')
def result():
    search = request.forms.get('search')
    return 'it worked'
```

When using bottle and tested it, it worked fine, but when I try to deploy it to OpenShift, I get a name error, "global variable 'request' is not defined" when in testing it worked perfectly with just bottle before deploying to openshift, does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: What does it show in your log files?

Comment: NameError: global name'request' is not defined.

Comment: Guessing that's from the 'search = request.forms.get(search)' line?

Comment: Did you import `request`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you haven't imported the request or route to namespace:

```
from bottle import get, post, request # or route

@get('/login') # or @route('/login')
def login():
    return '''
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            Username: <input name="username" type="text" />
        ...        
    '''

@post('/login') # or @route('/login', method='POST')
def do_login():
    user = request.forms.get('username')
    pass = request.forms.get('password')
     ...
```